# Django allauth access views

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to use django-allauth and provide links to allauth views from inside my custom templates. Here is the relevant template code:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <a href="{% url 'allauth.account.views.logout' %}">Sign Out</a>
{% else %}
      <a href="#user-form" class="popup-with-form">Login</a> <a href="#user-form2" class="popup-with-form2">Register</a> 
{% endif %}
```

This is checking if the user is authenticated, if so, provides a Logout link. I have used this exact code in past projects with no issue. In those projects I was using `django-allauth==0.12.0`. I thought my issue could be that I was using the most current version of allauth for this project (`0.16.x`) but even when I roll back to `0.12.0` I am still getting the same error. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The error I'm getting is

`NoReverseMatch at /app/`

```
Reverse for 'allauth.account.views.logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Whats the error? and version of Django?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've included my error in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following line at top of your template:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

The URL name enclosed in quotes is not compatible with Django < 1.5. For compatibility load the above library in template and it should work fine. See the note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi).

P.S you could just use the URL name, see [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py#L10) every URL has a name defined which can be used in templates:

```
{% url 'account_logout' %}
```